# Testthat and covr in one go

Tags: r, testthat, covr

I would like to run tests for a package with `testthat` and compute code coverage with `covr`. Furthermore, the results from `testthat` should be saved in the JUnit XML format and the results from `covr` should be saved in the Cobertura format.

The following code does the trick (when `getwd()` is the root of the package):

```
options("testthat.output_file" = "test-results.xml")
devtools::test(reporter = testthat::JunitReporter$new())

cov <- covr::package_coverage()
covr::to_cobertura(cov, "coverage.xml")
```

However, the tests are executed *twice*. Once with `devtools::test` and once with `covr::package_coverage`.

My understanding is that `covr::package_coverage` executes the tests, but it does not produce `test-results.xml`.

As the title suggests, I would like get both `test-results.xml` and `coverage.xml` with a single execution of the test suite.

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution. I have accepted the two runs.

Comment: Hm, alright thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the covr reference manual (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/covr/covr.pdf)

> This function uses `tools::testInstalledPackage()` to run the code, if you would like to test your package in another way you can set `type = "none"` and pass the code to run as a character vector to the `code` parameter

```
covr::package_coverage(
    type = "none",
    code = "testthat::test_package(
'myPackage',
reporter = testthat::JunitReporter$new(file = 'test-results.xml')
)")
```